# Mms in android showing "You can't add this picture to your message"

Tags: android

There are other questions in MMs but none have solved my issue and i simply don't know why!!

```
String fileName = "/one.png";
                    File dataFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath());
                    Toast.makeText(c, String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     if(dataFile.exists())
                     {


                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                    shareIntent.setType("image/*"); 


                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath()+fileName));
                    Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
                    new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                    c.getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);

                     }

                     else
                     {
                         Toast.makeText(c, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }
```

what is i am doing wrong!!